# radio button hide and show form content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I would like create registration form based on which country.
default address form is the default visible input
when customer click on the non-uk radio button then automatically hide uk form and oppen non-uk address form

I think I need to use javascript or JQuery for this function.

could any one give me an advice for this function.
if you think my question is not acceptable could you please don't decrease my rate. 
I can remove my question if u don't like.

here is my form code

```html
<form action="sent.php" name="form1" method="post">
  Name
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <br />UK
  <input type="radio" name="from" value="UK">
  <br />Address Line 1
  <input type="text" name="ad1" />
  <br />Address Line 2
  <input type="text" name="ad2" />
  <br />Town
  <input type="text" name="town" />
  <br />Post Code
  <input type="text" name="post_code" />
  <br />EU
  <input type="radio" name="from" value="UK">
  <br />Address Line 1
  <input type="text" name="ad1" />
  <br />Address Line 2
  <input type="text" name="ad2" />
  <br />Town
  <input type="text" name="town" />
  <br />Post Code
  <input type="text" name="post_code" />
  <br />Country
  <input type="text" name="post_code" />
  <br />
</form>
```

Comment: My advise would be to get started on your javascript or jQuery function and come back to StackOverflow when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all the input elements except the radiobuttons in two different divs so you can catch the change event for the radio buttons and show and hide two divs accordingly.

Comment: I think DIV should be better
Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to show or hide the elements necessarily as the form elements seem to be the same on both 'forms', consider :

```
<form action="sent.php" name="form1" method="post">

Name <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
UK <input type="radio" name="from" value="UK" > / EU <input type="radio" name="from" value="EU" ><br />

Address Line 1 <input type="text" name="ad1" /> <br />
Address Line 2 <input type="text" name="ad2" /> <br />
Town <input type="text" name="town" /> <br />
Post Code <input type="text" name="post_code" /> <br />

</form>
```

And then when you request the "from" parameter, you'll know which country they're from?

Comment: Ok, possibly be more specific next time, as you did add a closing form tag :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a class to represent which elements are UK address elements and which are EU or, as Élodie Petit, answered wrap them in a div and then either show or hide them depending on which radion button was selected.
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbG9U/) using the latter option.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution for it with JQuery

With JQuery support

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='from']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#c" + test).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

here is the html code suppurated with div

```
<form action="sent.php" name="form1" method="post">
<label>UK <input type="radio" name="from" value="1" ></label><br />
<label>EU <input type="radio" name="from" value="2" ></label><br />
<div id="c1" class="desc">
Name <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
Address Line 1 <input type="text" name="ad1" /> <br />
Address Line 2 <input type="text" name="ad2" /> <br />
Town <input type="text" name="town" /> <br />
Post Code <input type="text" name="post_code" /> <br />
</div>
<div id="c2" class="desc" style="display:none;">
Address Line 1 <input type="text" name="ad1" /> <br />
Address Line 2 <input type="text" name="ad2" /> <br />
Town <input type="text" name="town" /> <br />
Post Code <input type="text" name="post_code" /> <br />
Country <input type="text" name="post_code" /> <br />
</div>
</form>
```